# elasticsearch showing different beats with different dates

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I installed ELK but whenever I run "curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'"

I get indexes like topbeat, metricbeat, filebeat and so on but a lot of them are repeating and with different date in their names, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are running beats and sending data to your cluster. In that case what you are seeing is expected and default config of beats, which is to use a separated index per day.